# not proper working of ternary operator in expression language in td tag style

Tags: html, jsp, ternary

I have following code in my jsp page for td tag

```
<td style="${(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback lt 0 ? -1*(r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback) : r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback ) le reference44rb ? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}" >
```

but when ever I'm getting negative value by r.p44_readback-row.p44_readback, i need to convert it into positive sign and then compare it with other value and set the backcolor accordingly.But it is not working properly.I just want to use absolute value of subtraction and do comparison with reference44rb .

Comment: I don't know which language this is, but isn't there some function `abs()` or `absolute()`?

Comment: @Reeno,I'm using expression language in jsp to do this.No I can't find absolut() in it